# Alert not showing on popstate in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I am trying to show an `alert` when clicking the back button in Chrome. It is working properly in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Where do I need to change the code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href); 
    alert('Back button was pressed.');
  });
});
```

Comment: Does Chrome give any warnings/errors related to this in the Console?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp

Comment: no not showing any warning in console

Comment: What about the breakpoints you set when you are debugging? Does it hit in Chrome?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306510/alert-on-browser-back-button-click-or-page-refresh try this

Comment: Yes. But it's skipping the alert section.

Comment: Yes Abhishek ,I had tried this earlier and it's not working. Not even on reload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611937/addeventlistener-not-triggering-when-used-in-a-chrome-extension.                                                                      I Tried your method. this works in chrome when you do 1 click on the page. It may be how popstate is managed in chrome.

Comment: Abhishek,  alert pops if I first click on A-tag even if I don't click on back button. And If I click back button after once a-tag is clicked, alert is shown. This A-tag doesn't redirect to any site or anything .

Comment: JohnPete22 ,It skips this part when I set breakpoints while debugging. It catches it if (a-tag) is clicked. `history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href); 
    alert('Back button was pressed.');`